# Forecasting future values in LSTM?

Tags: python, lstm

```
# generate the input and output sequences
n_lookback = 20  # length of input sequences (lookback period)
n_forecast = 20  # length of output sequences (forecast period)

# generate the forecasts
X_ = df[- n_lookback:]  # last available input sequence
X_ = X_.reshape(1, n_lookback, 1)

Y_ = model.predict(X_).reshape(-1, 1)
Y_ = scaler.inverse_transform(Y_)

# organize the results in a data frame
df_past = dataset
df_past.rename(columns={'Harga': 'Actual'}, inplace=True)
df_past['Forecast'] = np.nan
df_past['Forecast'].iloc[-1] = df_past['Actual'].iloc[-1]

df_future = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Tanggal', 'Actual', 'Forecast'])
df_future['Tanggal'] = pd.date_range(start=df_past['Tanggal'].iloc[-1] + pd.Timedelta(days=1), periods=n_forecast)
df_future['Forecast'] = Y_.flatten()
df_future['Actual'] = np.nan

results = df_past.append(df_future).set_index('Tanggal')
```

Here is the full codes
https://pastebin.com/VZ5u5dLp
When I tried to run it I could only generate an n+1 forecast*,* but I couldnt get n-steps ahead forecast. For example*,* even when I use 20 days of values as the baseline of the forecast, I could only get 1 day into the future. When I tried to modify the n_forecast into numbers other than 1, it would generate a ValueError. Could somebody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [MCVE]. You could also perform inference `n_forecast ` times and with each inference append the last prediction.